# Warning: One or more disk image files are not currently accessible

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I have set up Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on VirtualBox.

Everything seems to work ok so far, but every time I launch VirtualBox I get this pop-up with a warning message.

[image]

I *believe* this warning started to appear when I changed the number of processor cores of the VM in **Settings**.

Is this a big issue and if so how can I fix this ?

This is what I see when I click the check button

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also  got this message but in my case, i did not mount drive where my iso file exist which i used to create vm. i resolved it after i mount the drive. Click `check` and it will tell you where the problem occur.

Comment: You also may still have an old VDI file attached that does no longer exist. Check with the "Virtual Media Manager".

Comment: @Lnux I have updated the topic, with a screenshot of the Virtual Media Manager ot review

Comment: @Takkat not sure if I understand you, but do you mean this warning occures because virtual box can't find the path to the .iso file ??

Comment: @Lykos: may well be... *remove* that ISO from media manager and see if the error went away.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same issue and was confused until I looked more closely and realized it was looking for the iso I originally placed on my desktop, which I had since thrown in the trash. It appears your message is telling you the same thing.

After successfully installing the ubuntu VM(/Users/user/VirturalBox VMs on mac), I discarded the ISO, but the drive is still mounted, causing the error, or warning.

I was able to select the iso listed in the dialog and press remove, and upon restart of VirtualBox, the issue was resolved.